# Buffer polygon invalid linearRing found (coordinates are not closed)

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to implement a buffer polygon around the input geometry at a specified distance.

So to solve this I looked at this GitHub solution https://github.com/RanaRanvijaySingh/PolygonBuffer

However, the buffered polygon coordinates I get back don't form a linear ring because it doesn't have the same start and end point. In my case it is something like this

Starting coordinates `32.415432800000005, -99.74657348418737`

End coordinates `Infinity, -Infinity`

This is the code I have used to generated the buffered polygon

```
 val pointList = coordinateArray.map { Point(it[0], it[1]) }

 //Distance you want to be from original shape. Approx : 0.0001 is 3-5 meter distance on ground
 val distance = 0.0001
 val bufferedPolygonList: List<Point> = AreaBuffer.buffer(pointList, distance)

 val newBufferedCoordinateArray = bufferedPolygonList.map { mutableListOf( it.x, it.y ) }.toMutableList()
```

I am not sure how to solve this issue? Any suggestions?